# Excel if, vlookup, database

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am a military helicopter instructor pilot teaching new aviators how to fly. We have a schedule in place that works off of what we call training days that go in numerical order. For instance, today you might be on training day 17, tomorrow will be 18, the following day 19, and so on. With each training day, we progressively introduce new maneuvers in order to achieve the goal of a fully qualified aviator. For operational security reasons, all of those tasks are not listed in this example.

Problem: I would like to devise a more efficient way of tracking which maneuvers we have to do on our current training day. In the uploaded photo, you will find a screenshot of a spreadsheet with color boxes drawn in on it.

- The blue box on the left shows what training day the student is currently on.
- The red box below it will list out what maneuvers that student is supposed to be trained on for that day.
- On the right side of the sheet you will find another blue box, and a green box. The blue box correlates to the blue box on the left, while the green box correlates to the red box on the left.

When a particular training day is entered into the blue box on the left, I want Excel to then reference the column under the blue box on the right. So in the example, training day 14. I then want Excel to reference column "X", where the blue box on the right is, and find all of the training days that are 14 and below. From there the tasks associated with those 14 and below days that it finds, I want it to populate under maneuvers, where the red box is at.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhEkt.jpg]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Can you please 1.) manually mock up the desired result, 2.) **edit your question** and post that desired result as another screenshot, then 3.) explain the logic using cell addresses, rather than "training day 24" which nobody knows what that refers to. Because right now, nobody knows where you want to see what and why. And please keep the narrative on topic.

Answer (score 1):

*Check this Screen Shot. For better understanding I've included only required Columns.*

[image]

*Use this Array Formula in Manoeuvres Column and drag down till required.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($E$248:$F$253, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$246, $F$248:$F$253), ROW($E$248:$F$253)-MIN(ROW($E$248:$F$253))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**NB:** Finish the Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

Column E and F are Task Title & Training Days. Cell C246 in Red Colour is match Value 14 (Training Days).

Adjust the Cell address in Formula, according to Data placement in your Sheet.

*Hope this help You.*